# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Rails project, Cross Domain, No route matches [OPTIONS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cors

I am implementing an API into my Rails project: and i have a sample HTML page to test my implementation on my rails site... I can not change the coding on the site that sends the request. (Code Below). I have to make my rails project accept the request.

I have this included in my ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :allow_cross_domain_access
  def allow_cross_domain_access
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  end
```

When i use this to post to my site i get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.65:3000/post_everywhere/0/loads. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404
```

rails Console shows:

```
  Started OPTIONS "/post_everywhere/0/loads" for 192.168.1.184 at 2015-02-02 09:20:42 -0600
  2015-02-02 09:20:42 FATAL --
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/post_everywhere/0/loads"):
```

The Thing is i want it to `POST` not use `OPTIONS`

i set my routes up like this:

```
  resources :post_everywhere do
    post :create_account
    post :update_account
    post :validate_account
    post :loads
    post :trucks
  end
```

I tried this but it doesnt work for me because it is looking for a template:

```
match 'post_everywhere/0/loads' => 'post_everywhere#loads', :via => [:get, :post, :options]
```

**CODE THAT I CAN NOT CHANGE:**  This is how the other site sends me the info.

```
function postLoad(remove) {
    try {
        var postToURL = document.getElementById("postToURL").value;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
        else alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
        xmlhttp.open("POST", postToURL, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "text/xml");
        xmlhttp.send(formatLoadPost(remove));
    }
    catch(e) { alert(e); }
}
function formatLoadPost(remove) {
    try {
        postXML = "<PELoadPostings><PostingAccount>";
        postXML += "<UserName>" + document.getElementById("login").value + "</UserName>";
        postXML += "<Password>" + document.getElementById("password").value + "</Password>";
        postXML += "<ContactName>" + document.getElementById("contactName").value + "</ContactName>";
        postXML += "<ContactPhone>" + document.getElementById("contactPhone").value + "</ContactPhone>";
        postXML += "<ContactFax>" + document.getElementById("contactFax").value + "</ContactFax>";
        postXML += "<ContactEmail>" + document.getElementById("contactEmail").value + "</ContactEmail>";
        postXML += "<CompanyName>" + document.getElementById("companyName").value + "</CompanyName>";
        postXML += "<UserID>" + document.getElementById("userID").value + "</UserID>";
        if (remove) postXML += "</PostingAccount><RemoveLoads>" + document.getElementById("loadData").value + "</RemoveLoads></PELoadPostings>";
        else postXML += "</PostingAccount><PostLoads>" + document.getElementById("loadData").value + "</PostLoads></PELoadPostings>";
        return postXML;
    }
    catch(e) { alert(e); }
}
```

I have implemented your solution and now i get this:

```
Started OPTIONS "/api/v3/post_everywhere/loads" for 192.168.1.184 at 2015-02-02 11:40:33 -0600
2015-02-02 11:40:33 INFO -- Processing by Api::V3::PostEverywhereController#loads as */*
2015-02-02 11:40:33 WARN -- WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2015-02-02 11:40:34 INFO --   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
2015-02-02 11:40:34 INFO -- Filter chain halted as :cors_preflight_check rendered or redirected
2015-02-02 11:40:34 INFO -- Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 11.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :cors_preflight_check rendered or redirected
```

console log

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.65:3000/api/v3/post_everywhere/loads. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I am not want a text templete I am wanting to pull in the params...

but it didnt display the params (the XML)

```
  def loads
    puts params
    render json: { success: true }
  end
```

I finally figured it out how to XML doc now as well...

```
  def loads
    xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)
    render json: { success: true }
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CORS requires you to respond to OPTIONS before accepting any other requests. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4) gives an example of how to do that. The important part is

```
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

This will catch any request with method 'OPTIONS', and respond with the correct headers and no content. Then the client application can send a post, which will be routed as per your routes.rb file. See also [wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: I added more info after my question there. I am still having issues as you will see...